# How can I match/adjust two clips together with a smooth transition?

Tags: sound, audacity

Currently I'm trying to replace the last refrain of a song with the first one (in the last one I didn't like their screams which weren't contained in the first one). Of course the transition between these two clips are not perfect and you're able to hear the transition quite clearly. Therefore I need to match them together, but I couldn't find a solution.

I've already tried 2 different things. To match them together I've extended one of these 2 clips and merged the tracks. But the sound in the part where they've been overlapped was way too loud and the bass was messed up a bit.

So I tried to fix it by using 'fade out' in the one track and 'fade in' in the other. But then the part became quieter at first and in the middle of that part it became louder.

A person explained to me to mute one of the tracks in that part (make this part grey like you do it for the whole one, but this time only a part of it). Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do it. I was only able to convert this part into silence, but then this overlapping would have no meaning.
Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a crossfade between the two tracks.

Crossfading is slightly different from a normal fade in/out. Instead of a linear transition, crossfading uses a logarithmic curve to keep the volume constant all the way through.

Audacity has built-in crossfading effects if you want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Cross fading as already mentioned. I just wanted to add that you can also manually do it. Create a second channel with the exact same settings as the channel you want to edit. Then copy the the part you want there. Make the part you want overlap with the part on the first channel and do the cross fading. That means start a fade out on the first channel on the exact same point when you start the fade in on the second channel. When the first channel reaches silence the second channel should reach max volume. The duration of the crossfade is up to you. You can for example make the fade-in/-out about 1-2 seconds long.

[image: I found this image online as an example]

Answer (score 0):

I do it all the time and the most accurate method (if a little time consuming) is to edit the wave file and copy and paste the new bit over the bit to be replaced. It's probably best done in a DAW because you can nudge things relative to each other and have two tracks running together and test the "join" for clicks. Trial it out with two tracks until you are perfectly happy then bounce the two tracks down to a new single track.

It's ALWAYS wise to "join" the new parts at points of zero crossing of the signal in each section. This is made more difficult when the track is stereo because a rising zero cross that's appropriate for left may not match with a zero cross for the right channel. What can happen is that you get a slight click on the right channel - some trial and error is needed but it's still, fundamentally the best approach and, if necessary you can micro-edit the wave file to "force" a simultaneous zero cross on both left and right at the correct join point. It's never failed for me.